# Cryptic Moo (Perl) Error "Attempt to bless into a reference at..."

Tags: mongodb, perl, cpan, moo, bless

Probably a long shot but I'm wondering if anyone has seen an error like this before, as I can not reproduce it outside of a production environment. Essentially the situation is as follows:

1. I have a module called `My::Budget::Module` (renamed for simplicity) which is responsible for updating the "budget" for a given object in the application
2. The `My::Budget::Module` uses a `Moo` object that I built called `My::Bulk::Update::Module` which does the following:

   - build up an array of database rows that need to be updated
   - build a MySQL update query string / statement which will update all rows at once
   - actually update all rows at once
3. The `My::Bulk::Update::Module` will then perform the update and mark the rows that have been updated as "stale" so that they will not be cached

The error always seems to occur somewhere after adding a row to be updated but before the code which actually applies the update returns.

If you look at the stack trace that I have included below you can see that the error takes the form

`Attempt to bless into a reference at...`

and the point at which this occurs is in the constructor of `Moo/Object.pm` which is `Version 2.003002` of `Moo` from `cpan`(see [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo)).

```
Attempt to bless into a reference at /path/to/module/from/cpan/Moo/Object.pm line 25 at /path/to/module/from/cpan/Moo/Object.pm line 25.
Moo::Object::new(My::Bulk::Update::Module=HASH(0xf784b50)) called at (eval 1808) line 28
MongoDB::Collection::new(My::Bulk::Update::Module=HASH(0xf784b50)) called at /path/to/my/bulk/update/module line XXXX
My::Bulk::Update::Module::apply_bulk_update(My::Bulk::Update::Module=HASH(0xf784b50)) called at /path/to/my/budget/module line XXXX
My::Budget::Module::update_budget(My::Budget::Module=HASH(0xf699a38)) called at /path/to/my/budget/module line XXXX
```

Moving backwards through the stack trace leads to `MongoDB::Collection` & this is where things start to get very weird.

`MongoDB::Collection` is also a `cpan` module but the module which appears at this point varies and I can't see a pattern here except that it is always a `Moo` object. Moreover, I'm unsure why this module is being instantiated as there is no call to `MongoDB::Collection::new` at the line mentioned.

In addition, from the stack trace it looks like `MongoDB::Collection` and `Moo::Object` are instantiated with the first argument being `My::Bulk::Update::Module=HASH(0xf784b50)`. Given the application logic I do not believe `MongoDB::Collection` should be instantiated here nor should `My::Bulk::Update::Module` be passed to `MongoDB::Collection` at all.

Other than the fact that it is a `Moo` object, `My::Bulk::Update::Module` does not extend any other module and is designed to be a stand alone "utility" module. It is only used at one place in the entire application.

Has anyone seen something similar before?

**EDIT:** Adding some more code - `apply_bulk_update` doesn't do much at all. There is no call to `MongoDB::Collection` here and `MongoDB::Collection` just "happens" to be the moudule included in the stack trace in this particular example. This is not always `MongoDB::Collection` - I've also seen `MongoDB::Timestamp`, `MongoDB::Cursor`, `Search::Elasticsearch::Serializer::JSON`, `Search::Elasticsearch::Logger::LogAny` etc etc

```
sub apply_bulk_update
{
    my $self = shift;
    my ($db) = @_; # wrapper around DBI module

    my $query  = $self->_generate_query(); # string UPDATE table SET...
    my $params = $self->_params; # arrayref

    return undef unless $params && scalar @$params;

    $db->do($query, undef, @$params);        
}
```

The code sometimes dies as soon as `apply_bulk_update` is called, sometimes on the call to `_generate_query` and sometimes after the query executes on the last line...

Comment: You need to post a short piece of code that reproduces the problem. Without being able to debug it ourselves there is only a very slim chance that we can help you.

Comment: Please show the relevant code, at least the `My::Bulk::Update::Module::apply_bulk_update()` method and the inheritance structure of that module. The error seems to indicate that you are calling a class method on an instance, e.g. `$instance->foo` instead of `Package->foo`.

Comment: I concur. Most likely suspect is `apply_bulk_update`. It calls `MongoDB::Collection::new($obj)` when that method expects `MongoDB::Collection::new($package)`.

Comment: See [this discussion](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=859439).

Comment: Thanks, I've added more code to show what `apply_bulk_update` does but I doubt this will be helpful. I'd love to be able to provide code that reproduces this error but I don't have any. I realise the chances of someone being able to help are slim...

Comment: Can you verify in your code that `$self, $query, $params, $db` are all their expected values before the exception happens? E.g. the stack trace indicates that `apply_bulk_update()` is called as a method with no extra arguments, but expects a `$db` argument. By the way, “Wrapper around DBI module” sounds suspicious. Is that class by chance called `DB`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case anyone was interested...

After a chunk of further debugging the error was traced to the exact point where `My::Bulk::Update::Module::apply_bulk_update` or `My::Bulk::Update::Module::_generate_query` was called but logging code inside these subroutines determined that they were not being executed as expected.

To determine what was going on `B::Deparse` was used to rebuild the source code for the body of these subroutines (or at least the source code located at the memory address to which these subs were pointing)

After using this library e.g.

`B::Deparse->new->coderef2text(\&My::Bulk::Update::_generate_query)`

it became obvious that the error occurred when `My::Bulk::Update::_generate_query` was pointing at a memory location which contained something entirely different (i.e. `MongoDB::Collection::new` etc).

This issue appears to have been solved upstream by the following commit in the `Sub::Defer` module (which is a dependency for `Moo`).

https://github.com/moose/Sub-Quote/commit/4a38f034366e79b76d29fec903d8e8d02ee01896

If you read the summary of the commit you can see the change that was made:

> **Prevent defer_info and undefer_sub from operating on expired subs.** Validate that the arguments to defer_info and undefer_sub refer to
>   actual live subs.  Use the weak refs we are storing to the deferred and
>   undeferred subs to make sure the original subs are still alive, and we
>   aren't returning data related to a reused memory address. Also make sure we don't expire data related to unnamed subs.  Since the
>   user can capture the undeferred sub via undefer_sub, we can't track the
>   expiry without using a fieldhash.  For now, avoid introducing that
>   complexity, since the amount we leak should not be that great.

Upgrading the version of `Sub::Defer` appears to have solved the issue.